# putting node on heroku- Getting started

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am a begineer with Node and Heroku.

Was going through this link  **https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs** wherein they have a section "**Declare Dependencies With NPM**".

```
{
  "name": "node-example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "2.5.x"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.8.x"
  }
}
```

What i couldn't understand from this section is where do i keep my package.json file. also how do i install dependencies locally

thanks
Amit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep your package.json in the same directory as your source code (for starters, anyway). Install dependencies with npm (for example, "npm install express@2.5.x"). After you install the [Heroku toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/), then you can run your server locally with 'foreman start', and it will run the same way it would remotely on Heroku.

Comment: Yusuf, when i do foreman start it gives me an error saying Procfile does not exists? how and where do i create it

Comment: From your questions, I assume you haven't seen this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs . The procfile goes in the same directory as the package.json file.

Comment: well this is exactly what i am reading and the article does not tell what procfile is and where does it go?